# Changing Button Text - Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm currently developing my first app, and I'm having a bit of an issue. I've made a custom button using JavaScript, then by screenshotting I've been able to import it as a custom button into XCode. However, I'm unable to put any text on it; anything I do appears to the side. I've searched through other threads and found the following code:

```
[_Button setTitle:@"ClickMe!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

However, this just causes text to appear to the side of the custom button. Can anyone help me fix this?

EDIT: 
Here's my code in ViewController.h:

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton * RoadMap; 
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * myLabel;
```

And.. relevant code in ViewController.m

```
 _myLabel.text=@"Road Map";
 [_RoadMap removeFromSuperView];
 [_RoadMap setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.PNG"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you using foreground image for button.
Try to use background image:
`[_Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`
In this case text will rendered above the image.

**Update:**
Just remove these two lines of code:

```
_myLabel.text=@"Road Map";
[_RoadMap removeFromSuperView];
```

And add this line:

```
[_RoadMap setTitle:@"RoadMap" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Now it looks like I get two buttons on top of each other.. without any text. I declare the button in ViewController.h, and added this in ViewController.m.

Comment: @user3904846 Consider to add some code in question, it will be easier to see the problem

Comment: I've added relevant code from ViewController.h and .m

Comment: The same thing I stated earlier happened; two buttons without any text. Without the remove from super view, the button added in ViewController.h is still there.